# Correct messaging when all players fold

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

Given this scenario...

- Current pot 1000
- Player A bets 10
- Player B calls
- Player C raises to 100 (10 to call + 90 to raise)
- Player A folds
- Player B folds

What messaging should player C get? Should it be "you've won 1120" or "you've won 1030" because technically nobody called the 90 player C raised.

I've been discussing it with a friend who tells me that player C's chips were not added to the pot so should be 1030...but I'm not sure. I think any chips in-play are technically part of the pot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uncalled bet or raise is not part of the pot unless it is called. This pot is 1030. $1000 + Player A Bet $10 + Player B call $10 + player C call $10 = 1030. The 90 raise is not part of the pot until someone calls the raise.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So I guess the messaging should be "you've won 1030" and the 90 just gets returned without mentioning it.

A side question off this... does the value of the pot only get updated after the phase is finished? I'm assuming so but just want check.